# Fire an event within another event

Tags: c#, events

I need help on firing an event within C#

Basically I have a onclick event that fires when you click on a checkbox

```
void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
   ...
}
```

I need help on firing an event within C#

Basically I have a onclick event that fires when you click on a checkbox

```
void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
   ...
}
```

However, I need to fire this event once another event has been fired, so within this new event, is it possible I can fire the above one?

```
private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{     
   switch(dataGrid.Name)
   {
      case "Customer"
      //fire OnCLick Event
      break;
   }
}
```

I have tried something like

```
??? += new MouseEventHandler(OnClick);
```

But I am not sure if this will actually work.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just call the method? Like, call `OnClick(sender, new RoutedEventArgs(...))`?

Comment: Refactor the code running at the event into a class method, and call that directly.

Comment: Factor out the common code into a separate function and call _that_ from both event handlers.

Comment: @RobertSnyder I think they do as well. At least I thought they did in Windows Forms. But I'd be tempted to pull the contents of `OnClick` out into another, more appropriately named method, then call that from both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can, but only if the event is in your own class. You can't even raise a base class' event. You have a put a method in the base class to raise the event, and then call that.
2. The code you put there is adding another event handler, not raising an event; you don't need to do that.
3. If it's a button, use btnDoSomething.PerformClickEvent (winforms)
4. If the handler is in your code, you can call it without raising the event (commenters assume that this is what you want to do but in reaslity there are many cases where you'd need more than this) btnDoSomething_Click(null, null) - null usually works because handler code rarely cares about the sender or arguments and if you don't reference them, you don't need them.
5. If you can use #4, you can also refactor as mentioned. Usually not needed. But usually so easy to do you it's worth doing for clarity anyway.
6. For objects that map from Windows widgets of anysort, check out the SendMessage and PostMessage API calls. Wayyyy beyond the scope of this answer, though. Doesn't apply to non-windows-backed objects (but your sample implies windows).